# Searching in the help center isn't very helpful

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

A [question in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1486100#1486100) led me to search in the [help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help) to see if there was anything mentioned about the election process. I was surprised when searching for ["election"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=election) returned zero results, and assumed this meant that elections weren't mentioned at all.

But they *are* mentioned, at least briefly. The problem was that I should have been searching for ["election**s**"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=elections), which returns two results. The general site search isn't tripped up by these kinds of pluralization differences, and given the nature of the help center, the search there really shouldn't be either.

Comment: hahahahahaha this is so funny... It's akin to.. "Why are there so many dupes on Meta?" Cos it's so darn hard to search ;)

Comment: Search results returns only for exact keyword..Damn..

Comment: Same goes with `badge` which returns 1 result and `badges` returns 3

Comment: Brace yourself. This is a [pluralization bug](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105).  ;)

Comment: well, at least there's 1 result for elect, oh wait... that leads to "How does editing work"

Comment: @BilltheLizard I ain't afraid of no gho...codinghorror!

Comment: @OldCheckmark you found a typo in the help center with your search query. It should be "select" and not "elect".

Comment: Yes the search is somehow confusing. The same is true for `privileg` and `privileges`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fix for this just went out - the stemming analyzer was not appropriately being applied to the query here...it is now.